Facing accuracy challenges with Lagrange interpolation when using more than a few points.
I'm a senior in high school working on a paper for my maths course. I've been attempting to approximate a curve on Desmos with a set of points, and my teacher recommended I look into Lagrange interpolation. I found it simple to use at first, however I've now been running into an issue where defining more points to minimize the amount of approximation being done causes the curves to go a little haywire. For comparison, here are two examples using nearly the same data points, except the latter uses in-betweens.
Curve with less defined points
$A=\frac{\left(x-0.1\right)\left(x-0.2\right)\left(x-0.3\right)\left(x-0.37\right)\left(x-0.44\right)}{\left(0-0.1\right)\left(0-0.2\right)\left(0-0.3\right)\left(0-0.37\right)\left(0-0.44\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$B=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.2\right)\left(x-0.3\right)\left(x-0.37\right)\left(x-0.44\right)}{\left(0.1-0\right)\left(0.1-0.2\right)\left(0.1-0.3\right)\left(0.1-0.37\right)\left(0.1-0.44\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$C=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.1\right)\left(x-0.3\right)\left(x-0.37\right)\left(x-0.44\right)}{\left(0.2-0\right)\left(0.2-0.1\right)\left(0.2-0.3\right)\left(0.2-0.37\right)\left(0.2-0.44\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$D=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.1\right)\left(x-0.2\right)\left(x-0.37\right)\left(x-0.44\right)}{\left(0.3-0\right)\left(0.3-0.1\right)\left(0.3-0.2\right)\left(0.3-0.37\right)\left(0.3-0.44\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$E=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.1\right)\left(x-0.2\right)\left(x-0.3\right)\left(x-0.44\right)}{\left(0.37-0\right)\left(0.37-0.1\right)\left(0.37-0.2\right)\left(0.37-0.3\right)\left(0.37-0.44\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$F=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.1\right)\left(x-0.2\right)\left(x-0.3\right)\left(x-0.37\right)}{\left(0.44-0\right)\left(0.44-0.1\right)\left(0.44-0.2\right)\left(0.44-0.3\right)\left(0.44-0.37\right)}\left\{0.44\ge x\ge0\right\}$
$P_{s}=\left[\left(0,0.07\right),\left(0.1,0.05\right),\left(0.2,0.065\right),\left(0.3,0.1\right),\left(0.37,0.09\right),\left(0.44,0.0\right)\right]$
0.07A+0.05B+0.065C+0.1D+0.09E
Curve with more defined points / has in-betweens
$A=\frac{\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0-0.05375\right)\left(0-0.1075\right)\left(0-0.16125\right)\left(0-0.215\right)\left(0-0.26875\right)\left(0-0.3225\right)\left(0-0.37625\right)\left(0-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$B=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.05375-0\right)\left(0.05375-0.1075\right)\left(0.05375-0.16125\right)\left(0.05375-0.215\right)\left(0.05375-0.26875\right)\left(0.05375-0.3225\right)\left(0.05375-0.37625\right)\left(0.05375-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$C=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.1075-0\right)\left(0.1075-0.05375\right)\left(0.1075-0.16125\right)\left(0.1075-0.215\right)\left(0.1075-0.26875\right)\left(0.1075-0.3225\right)\left(0.1075-0.37625\right)\left(0.1075-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$D=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.1075-0\right)\left(0.1075-0.05375\right)\left(0.1075-0.16125\right)\left(0.1075-0.215\right)\left(0.1075-0.26875\right)\left(0.1075-0.3225\right)\left(0.1075-0.37625\right)\left(0.1075-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$E=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.215-0\right)\left(0.215-0.05375\right)\left(0.215-0.1075\right)\left(0.215-0.16125\right)\left(0.215-0.26875\right)\left(0.215-0.3225\right)\left(0.215-0.37625\right)\left(0.215-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$F=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.26875-0\right)\left(0.26875-0.05375\right)\left(0.26875-0.1075\right)\left(0.26875-0.16125\right)\left(0.26875-0.215\right)\left(0.26875-0.3225\right)\left(0.26875-0.37625\right)\left(0.26875-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$G=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.3225-0\right)\left(0.3225-0.05375\right)\left(0.3225-0.1075\right)\left(0.3225-0.16125\right)\left(0.3225-0.215\right)\left(0.3225-0.26875\right)\left(0.3225-0.37625\right)\left(0.3225-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$H=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.43\right)}{\left(0.37625-0\right)\left(0.37625-0.05375\right)\left(0.37625-0.1075\right)\left(0.37625-0.16125\right)\left(0.37625-0.215\right)\left(0.37625-0.26875\right)\left(0.37625-0.3225\right)\left(0.37625-0.43\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$I=\frac{\left(x-0\right)\left(x-0.05375\right)\left(x-0.1075\right)\left(x-0.16125\right)\left(x-0.215\right)\left(x-0.26875\right)\left(x-0.3225\right)\left(x-0.37625\right)}{\left(0.43-0\right)\left(0.43-0.05375\right)\left(0.43-0.1075\right)\left(0.43-0.16125\right)\left(0.43-0.215\right)\left(0.43-0.26875\right)\left(0.43-0.3225\right)\left(0.43-0.37625\right)}\left\{0\le x\le0.43\right\}$
$P_{s}=\left[\left(0,0.08\right),\left(0.05375,0.0575\right),\left(0.1075,0.0525\right),\left(0.16125,0.056\right),\left(0.215,0.072\right),\left(0.26875,0.09125\right),\left(0.3225,0.1\right),\left(0.37625,0.085\right),\left(0.43,0\right)\right]$
$0.08A_{1}+0.0575B_{1}+0.0525C_{1}+0.056D_{1}+0.072E_{1}+0.09125F_{1}+0.1G_{1}+0.085H_{1}$
The resulting graphs render as such in Desmos respectively:
First curve
Second curve
If possible, I'd like an explanation as to why this is happening, and whether or not it has to do with how I've written the math itself.

You might want to read overfitting and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200924/why-is-lagrange-interpolation-numerically-unstable .

Check for typos in the second curve
